# Sequelize with Postgresql order by with null values first

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I would like to construct a sequelize query that returns rows in ascending order with NULL values first.

I have a timestamp when an email is sent, which is NULL if an email has never been sent.

Here's the Postgres query that does what I want:

```
SELECT quote, quote_id
FROM quotes
WHERE book_id = '${book_id}'
ORDER BY last_emailed ASC NULLS FIRST
LIMIT 5
```

The sequelize query I have is:

```
const res = await Quote.findAll({
  attributes: ['quote', 'quote_id'],
  where: { book_id },
  order: [
    ['last_emailed', 'ASC']
  ],
  limit: 5,
})
```

But this returns all NULL values last. It otherwise does what I want

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Adding `NULLS FIRST` after `ASC` should give you the expected result :

```
const res = await Quote.findAll({
   attributes: ['quote', 'quote_id'],
   where: { book_id },
   order: [
      ['last_emailed', 'ASC NULLS FIRST']
   ],
   limit: 5,
})
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me with sequelize 6 & mysql

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer didn't work for me but adding an extra line in the order array like this worked:

```
const res = await Quote.findAll({
   attributes: ['quote', 'quote_id'],
   where: { book_id },
   order: [
      Sequelize.fn("isnull", Sequelize.col("last_emailed")),
      ['last_emailed', 'ASC']
   ],
   limit: 5,
})
```